# how to check metadata api in get request in postman Zoho CRM Developer account this issues replicate 401 unauthorized

Tags: crm, zoho

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qvA2.png)

I have a problem when I try to pull record from CRM. I got token and see something is true (token is valid and data center is in India). Please help me to fix it!

Comment: Hi, you need to ckeck the authorization tab, or the headers tab to check if you're sending the token properly. There is not enough information on that image for us to answer. (BTW please make sure not to post any tokens here)